# How to create ePub with title page from LaTeX source using pandoc

Tags: epub, linux, markdown, pandoc

I have a book written in LaTeX.  I can build an epub output file using pandoc, but I cannot get the epub title page right.  The final epub file is missing Title, Author and Date information.

```
$ pandoc -S -o mybook.epub --epub-cover-image=images/my_cover.png title.txt mybook.tex
```

I've tried a second book where the source is in markdown (not LaTeX) format.  The title page works correctly.

```
$ pandoc -S -o guide.epub title.txt part1.markdown part2.markdown
```

Is there a setting I am missing to get the YAML file (the title.txt file) correct when LaTeX is the source to pandoc?

I used LaTeX rather than markdown for the first book so I could use the [sffms](http://www.mcdemarco.net/sffms/) LaTeX document class.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to work around the issue as follows:

```
$ pandoc -S -o mybook.markdown   mybook.tex 
$ pandoc -S -o mybook.epub --epub-cover-image=images/my_cover.png  title.txt  mybook.markdown
```

By converting the LaTeX file to markdown, the second pandoc command was able to apply the Title, Author and Date information in title.txt to the epub file.

Comment: IIRC the title pages are specifically an extension of markdown, so it's unlikely that it'll ever be made to work with other formats.